# what is the use of resolve and how to send data from pop up screen to view in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I make a simple example in which I use **resolve** keyword.But I don't know what is the use of that.Let me explain the example .I have one button and textfield .What ever I write on text field and press click It open the pop up screen having same text which is written in the text field.
so my Question is what resolve mean? Secondly from where **textValue**: function call ?

```
resolve: {
          textValue:function(){
                  return $scope.textValue;
          }

              }
```

Secondly if I need to do vice versa how I can I achieve  this  ?In other words if I click button open the pop up screen write anything on text field and click submit button it display the text on input field.?how this can achieve ?

here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ulxiqEU62NuMWBMLWqkr?p=preview
how to change value

Comment: how to resolve issue ?

Comment: I don't think you understand what resolve is.  `$scope` wouldn't be accessible to the resolve function, resolve is basically for fetching data from the server before the view changes.  Your view change will wait on this data and inject it into your controller.

Comment: from where it will call textValue:function(){
                  return $scope.textValue;
          }..from where textvalue fuction call

Comment: i understand $scope.textValue take the value .but from where it will call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code to working in both ways. Check [plunkr] :http://plnkr.co/edit/EcXidf6oZ5pBQC4FPV7Z?p=preview

**About resolve function**
The resolve in $modal.open function means when resolve promise is successful, it will open the modal popup. 
This is part of [Angular Bootstrap library]: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
$modal is a service to quickly create AngularJS-powered modal windows.
I have copied following from documentation [Link]: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

```
resolve - members that will be resolved and passed to the controller as locals; it is equivalent of the resolve property for AngularJS routes
```

Though it is equivalent of the resolve property for angularjs routes, it mean here in the context of modal popup.

**Making the code work...**

For communication from modal controller (modalController) to cntr, I have used broadcast and on events.
On modal submit, I am raising the broadcast event and subscribed to it using following code.

Broadcasting event.

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast('modalSubmit', {
        modalText: $scope.modaldata.passedValue // send whatever you want
      });
```

Subscribing to event.

```
$scope.$on('modalSubmit', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
    $scope.textValue = data.modalText;
  });
```

There was one more problem. Please note the following code in modalController. I have faced this weird problem before as well. 
I replaced

```
$scope.passedValue = textValue;
```

with the following

```
$scope.modaldata = {
      passedValue: textValue
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple illustration of resolve:

```
angular.module('myApp',['people-services']).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/somepath',{
            controller : 'myCtrl',
            templateUrl : 'url/to/tmpl',
            resolve : {
                people : ['findPeopleSrvc',function(findPeopleSrvc){
                    return findPeopleSrvc.find().then(function(response){ // success
                        return response.data.people;
                    },function(){ // failed
                        return [];
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
        .when('/someotherpath',{
            controller : 'someOtherCtrl',
            templateUrl : 'url/to/some/other/tmpl'
        });
}]);
```

Then in your controller for **/somepath** the resolved data is injected as the last parameter:

```
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','people',function($scope,people){
    // .. do something here ...
}]);
```

If you have more than one resolved function in your resolve object then those will be tacked onto the parameter list of your controller function in succession as injected data.

Please note that *findPeopleSrvc* is just a made of service that returns a promise in order to illustrate the example.

Comment: sir i understand $scope.textValue take the value .but from where it will call

Comment: Resolve is a property of the `$routeProvider` service, it calls its functions to be resolved upon request for a route change automatically.  `$scope` will not be available.

Comment: Ok, i see you're trying to use UI-Bootstrap's modal service.  It works in much the same way, resolved functions will be tacked onto the end of the parameter list for the modal's controller.

Comment: `$scope` would be available in to the *modal.open* method, I thought you were talking about resolve in general as it happens with the `$routeProvider`

Answer (score 0):

From the link below: "A resolve contains one or more promises that must resolve successfully before the route will change. This means you can wait for data to become available before showing a view, and simplify the initialization of the model inside a controller because the initial data is given to the controller instead of the controller needing to go out and fetch the data."

Lots more information at the link.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: can you please explain how I will achieve vice versa.please remove your answer

Comment: Your first question is "so my Question is what resolve mean?", which this answers. If you were looking for something else, I suggest you edit your question to make that clearer.